# How to convert standardized string into a Pandas query with a Python function?

Tags: python, pandas, regex

The following text should get represented as:

some text column4 greater than n1 some text column2 less than n3 some other text column5 equal to n6

```
df[(df["column4"]>n1) & (df["column2"]<n3) & (df["column5"]==n6)]
```

some text column2 less than or equal to n1 some text column5 greater than n2

```
df[(df["column2"]<=n1) & (df["column5"]>n2)]
```

some text column2 less than or equal to n1 some text contains **or** somewhere column5 greater than n2

```
df[(df["column2"]<=n1) | (df["column5"]>n2)]
```

column5 column6 some text column2 less than or equal to n1 some text column5 greater than n2 n3 n4 column8

```
df[(df["column2"]<=n1) & (df["column5"]>n2)]
```

Note that the leading and trailing columnX and nX are ignored

column2 less than n1 and greater than n2 some text column5 greater than n3

```
df[(df["column2"]<n1) & (df["column2"]>n2) & (df["column5"]>n3)]
```

column2 less than n1 and greater than n2 SOME column4 column6 TEXT column5 greater than n3

```
df[(df["column2"]<n1) & (df["column2"]>n2) & (df["column5"]>n3)]
```

Note that column4 and column6 can be safely ignored

The number following columnX and nX can be anything that has to be taken into account while writing the query. The string can be of any length, but clearly, there is a structure that I believe can be exploited. Any help in this regard will be appreciated. I do not want to use machine learning for this.

Comment: So you want to convert plain text into Python (Pandas) code?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I have already written a small script using regex that can handle many of the cases, but I feel that I am not exploiting regex properly.

Comment: Since StackOverflow is not meant as a code writing service, but to help with errors, mistakes or other problems, could you add what code you have now, and point out where you are stuck? "not exploiting regex properly" is rather vague, especially without knowing what the regex(es) are and what is missing.